# Tizen smart-TV application on real device

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I have a simple smart-TV application which I display some videos and some channels on line, when I run on the emulator the video player don't work but if i run on the simulator it works good, and if I run on a real device (TV) I just got a black screen...my certificate is good . any one get this problem before ? solutions ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Simulator directly uses browser to run the application. To access online resource from emulator or real device add internet access privilege for your Tizen application in the config.xml file. Internet Privilege allows the application to access the Internet.

```
<tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

Also defining external access Policy may be required to access network. According to the W3C Access Requests Policy (WARP), you cannot access external network resources by default. If you require access to an external network resource, you must request network resource permissions for the Web application using the Policy in the config.xml file.

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

Now your application should be able to access internet from the emulator as well as real devices.